Vite build tries to generate sourcemaps for dependencies too #17923
I'm using vite@5.4.1 with react-ts template.
I have configured vite to build sourcemaps on build, the problem is it seems trying to build sourcemaps for dependencies too casing finally a failure due JS out of memory. Attached is a piece of the output:
> tsc -b && vite build

vite v5.4.1 building for production...
../../node_modules/antd/es/affix/index.js (1:0): Error when using sourcemap for reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error.
../../node_modules/antd/es/back-top/index.js (1:0): Error when using sourcemap for reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error.
../../node_modules/antd/es/auto-complete/index.js (1:0): Error when using sourcemap for reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error.

Any ideas how can I fix it?
